# I want to change the value of width according to HTML lang attribute in less or css

Tags: javascript, css, less

I want to change `.edit` width value according to HTML lang attribute in less or CSS

I want to do like this in less

```
.edit {
    &:lang(en) {
        @main-properties-width: 200px;
    }

    &:lang(de) {
        @main-properties-width: 295px;
    }

    width: @main-properties-width + 25px;
}
```

but this does not work, variable `@main-properties-width` is

> undefined !!

another way, I try to do like this

```
.edit {
    @lang: ? // ( i want to get html lang attribute value )

    & when (@lang = 'en') {
        @main-properties-width: 200px;
    }

    & when (@lang = 'de') {
        @main-properties-width: 295px;
    }

    width: @main-properties-width + 25px;
}
```

but the way, I don't know how to get HTML lang attribute value in CSS or less.

Is there a method to get lang in less or CSS?

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Why you save lang attribute value to a variable when you hard code to compare that.

Comment: And wouldn't `.edit` be a child ?

Comment: Why do you need a @main-properties-width variable?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this in css.

And just to be clear, in your case you would do it with lang attribute in html tag and then targeting it in css like this.

```
html[lang="fi"] .edit {}
```

DEMO:

```css
[lang="fi"] p {
  background: blue;
  color: white
}

[lang="en-us"] p {
  background: red;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div lang="fi">
  <p>This is in finnish</p>
</div>

<div lang="en-us">
  <p>This is in english(us)</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>This is generic</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @BoltClock i know man, was just showing how she/he should use it :)

Comment: I don't think you understand. I'm saying that :lang() *is* how it should be done. Not attribute selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock ah, goddamit :D

Comment: @VilleKoo Thank you for your answer. but, this is not the answer I seek.
I want to know that how to change the variable of Less according to Lang change.

Comment: @NoAnswer then you probably should rephrase the title of the question :)